# Need a clarification on partial deriatives.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, 3d, plane-geometry

Suppose I have a certain plane. I know that the plane is parallel to the plane z=0(3d coordinate system). Can I say that the partial deriatives of a certain surface equal to zero?

basically I need to find a certain plane that is tangent to a specific surface(some function) and is parallel to the z=0 plane.

Can I say that the partial deriatives equal to zero? because in the book they solve it in this way(which I don't really understand). what is the geometrcial meaning of taking a partial deriative of a certain surface and comparing it to zero?

The problem: $z=x^2y^2-2xy^2-6x^2y+12xy$  and there is some tangent plane to the function. find all the points on the plane, so that the plane is vertical to the vector (0,0,1)(there is no answer).

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain I edited the post, and listed the exerscie details. how is partial deriatives helps me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know how to find the tangent plane to the surface at a given point?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, but for that I need a point and a normal

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to the problem, and I'm not sure which is confusing you.  The equation of the tangent plane to the surface $z=f(x,y)$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$ is $$z=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)\tag{1}$$
assuming the partial derivatives exist.  See [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TangentPlanes.aspx) if you are unsure about this.

The second part is what it means for the tangent plane to be normal (not "vertical") to the vector $(0,0,1)$.  A normal vector to the plane $Ax+By+Cz=D$ has direction $(A,B,C)$.  (If we look at the parallel plane $Ax+By+Cz=0$,  it's clear that for any vector $(x,y,z)$ on the plane we have $(A,B,C)\cdot (x,y,z)=0$.)

Looking at $(1)$, we se that a normal vector is $$(-f_x(x_0,y_0),-f_y(x_0,y_0),1)$$ and if this is to be the same direction as $(0,0,1)$ the partial derivatives must vanish.